# Docker-compose second entry in yaml using a base image generated from first entry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i need to do the next with docker:

Having a docker-compose.yaml like

```
version: '2'

services:

  builder:
      image: "whatever-docker-image"
      command: "docker build -t builder ."

  local:
    image: "builder:latest" <----Image generated in prevoious command 
    depends_on: [builder]
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `build` combainde with `image` command instead of `command` [see this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/build)

```
version: '2'

services:

  builder:
      build: .
      image: builder

  local:
    image: "builder:latest" <----Image generated in prevoious command
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand where should i use build..Could u explain a bit more please?Thanks

Comment: Usually `command` is used to run a command when the container start up. `Image` is used for ger the start up image of service. `build` make an image starting from  Dockerfile

Comment: So, i need to change image: builder by build: builder, that is what you meant?

Comment: No, yuo need to change builder: image... container.... with `build: .` in the first service.

Comment: With this i'm having this error:

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local-deploy.yml up -d
Pulling local (builder:latest)...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/builder
ERROR: Error: image library/builder:latest not found

So, it is trying to get the image from docker.io instead of built a new one locally and use it..

Comment: Ok, it's my mistake. You should add `image: builder` after `build: .`. `image` set the name to image.

Comment: And now, how could i say to my builder, ey, you base image it's this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133262/discussion-between-giorgio-cerruti-and-colymore).